# Running Android tests automatically

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

I want to run Android tests automatically, but not just one time.
I want them to run one time, then change some property (in this case, the content of a file) and make them run again. Is there a way to do it automatically? Maybe some `TestRunner` class (like ***jUnit***) or something?

(edit)
The ideal approach will be something like this:

```
public class MyTestRunner(){
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Runner runner = new Runner();
        runner.addTests(MyTestClass.class);
        runner.runTests();
        /* With this I can run the tests with some 
         * operation between each test run */
    }
```

Please... I could realy use some help :/

Answer (score 0):

Android supports jUnit. You can read the following.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTesting/article.html

Comment: Android supports `jUnit 3`, that is for `jUnit 4`.
Besides, from what I know Android tests must be runned with `InstrumentationTestRunner` (defined in the Android Manifest file of the test project), and that approach uses `jUnitCore`.

Answer (score 0):

I started a github project to show how to integrate android testing in gradle build files.

It's https://github.com/Dornathal/AndroidGradleTests

You should be able to copy from the gradle build file and have a solid testing configuration to start your app from.